# exporting org-mode nested blocks to html

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Is there a way to convince org-mode to export nested blocks as nested `<blockquote>` elements?

This would be really cool to handle nested quotes in html emails with mu4e.

```
#+BEGIN_QUOTE
hey ho
#+BEGIN_QUOTE
 hey hey
#+END_QUOTE
ho ho
#+END_QUOTE
```

Currently the exporter outputs:

```
<blockquote>
    <p>
        hey ho
    </p>
    <p>
        #+BEGIN<sub>QUOTE</sub>
        hey hey
    </p>
</blockquote>
<p>
    ho ho
</p>
<p>
    #+END<sub>QUOTE</sub>
</p>
```

While I would expect it to output:

```
<blockquote>
    <p>
        hey ho
    </p>
    <blockquote>
        <p>
            hey hey
        </p>
    </blockquote>
    <p>
        ho ho
    </p>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: It is (now) unclear to me what you want. Before the last edit by @Unihedron it sounded like you wanted something like `<blockquote>foo<blockquote>bar</blockquote>baz</blockquote>`. Please edit your question and state exactly **(a)** what the output *currently* looks like and **(b)** what the output produced by the exporter *should* look like.

Comment: @itsjeyd true, edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, org-mode can be *coerced* into exporting nested `<blockquote>` elements.

**1.  Create *inner quote* inside `org` code block. Add `:results html` header to code block.**

```
        #+NAME: inner-quote-org
        #+BEGIN_SRC org  :results html replace 

           ,#+BEGIN_QUOTE
           hey hey
           ,#+END_QUOTE

        #+END_SRC
```

**2.  Create *outer quote* inside `org` code block and put a language specific variable, e.g. ruby syntax, as place holder for *inner quote*.**

```
        #+NAME: outer-quote-org
        #+BEGIN_SRC org :results html replace

        ,#+BEGIN_QUOTE
        hey ho
        #{inner_quote}
        ho ho
        ,#+END_QUOTE

        #+END_SRC
```

**3.  Create new code block, e.g. ruby, with a matching`:var` header, e.g `:var inner_quote="Hello World!"`. Then add `:noweb yes` header to insert *outer quote* block. Add `:results` header so output will rendered as `html`.**

```
        #+NAME: nested-quotes-html 
        #+BEGIN_SRC ruby :var inner_quote="Hello World!" :results html replace 
          output = <<-ORGSRC
          <<outer-quote-org()>>
          ORGSRC
        #+END_SRC
```

---

**Finished code blocks should look similar to example below:**

```
        #+NAME: inner-quote-org
        #+BEGIN_SRC org  :results html replace 

           ,#+BEGIN_QUOTE
           hey hey
           ,#+END_QUOTE

        #+END_SRC

        #+NAME: outer-quote-org
        #+BEGIN_SRC org :results html replace

        ,#+BEGIN_QUOTE
        hey ho
        #{inner_quote}
        ho ho
        ,#+END_QUOTE

        #+END_SRC

        #+NAME: nested-quotes-html 
        #+BEGIN_SRC ruby :var inner_quote="Hello World!" :results html replace 
          output = <<-ORGSRC
          <<outer-quote-org()>>
          ORGSRC
        #+END_SRC
```

---

**To export nested `<blockquote>` as HTML, use `#+CALL:` with `:results html`.**

```
        #+CALL: nested-quotes-html(inner_quote=inner-quote-org()) :results html replace
```

**Notice:** `inner_quote=inner-quote-org()` is how we dynamically set value of *inner quote* **after** *outer quote* was rendered as `html`.

---

**Result exported as HTML using `C-c` `C-e` `h H`**

```
        <blockquote>
        <p>
        hey ho
        <blockquote>
        <p>
        hey hey
        </p>
        </blockquote>

        ho ho
        </p>
        </blockquote>
```

---

Hope that helped!

I use a similar technique to create dynamic nested code templates using `org` code blocks that send output to a `drawer`. It works really well but I'm always looking for a better method.

---

Code tested using

> `GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0, NS apple-appkit-1343.14)`
>
> `Org-mode version 8.3.1 (8.3.1-87-g4ef2c0-elpa)`

Answer (score 4):

You get the correct and expected output.  Per the Org Syntax, (Greater) Elements cannot contain (Greater) Elements of the same type.  Please refer to the [Org Syntax](http://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-syntax.html#Greater_Elements).  You are free to install violations/hacks of the syntax via filters but I think it won't be easy in this case.

The Syntax makes sense.  I only know *your* expected output of the given input because you told me!  There is not a unique way to match the `#+BEGIN_QUOTE` and `#+END_QUOTE` in your example and naturally the first match is assumed to be the matching ending.

Alternatively, you can use another `special block` within your `quote` block and fix it with a filter ex post.

```
(defun rasmus/org-html-myquote-to-quote (block backend info)
  (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'html)
    (when (string-match "\\`<div class=\"MYQUOTE\">" block)
      (setq block (replace-match "<blockquote>" t nil block))
      (string-match "</div>\n\\'" block)
      (setq block (replace-match "</blockquote>\n" t nil block))
      block)))

(let ((org-export-filter-special-block-functions
      '(rasmus/org-html-myquote-to-quote)))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert "
#+BEGIN_QUOTE
hey ho
#+BEGIN_MYQUOTE
 hey hey
#+END_MYQUOTE
#+BEGIN_ANOTHER_SPECIAL_BLOCK
is preserved as is
#+END_ANOTHER_SPECIAL_BLOCK
ho ho
#+END_QUOTE")
      (org-html-export-as-html nil nil nil t)))
```

`=>`

```
<blockquote>
<p>
hey ho
</p>
<blockquote>
<p>
hey hey
</p>

</blockquote>
<div class="ANOTHER_SPECIAL_BLOCK">
<p>
is preserved as is
</p>

</div>
<p>
ho ho
</p>
</blockquote>
```